# To get the Year of the previous month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the year of the previous month.

For example in July 2017 I want result 2017. But in January 2017 I want result 2016 and in Feb 2017 I want result 2017. Using SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sql server?

```
select datepart(year, dateadd(month, -1, getdate()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select year(dateadd(month,-1,GETDATE()));
```

Comment: downvoted.  It's a virtual duplicate of my answer which was there 5 minutes before this one.

Comment: I disagree. The results are the same using a different method. There's multiple ways to do this, but the two listed here are the easiest IMHO and any *other* way would be more complicated than it needs to be. I prefer datepart for clarity, but it's preference.

Comment: @DanBracuk I got busy and posted my answer without refreshing and knowing that someone had answered already. I am sorry I did not know that it was a competition of who replies first.

Comment: One of the stack overflow rules is to not plagiarize, as Guru0008 did with your answer.  Whether or not you plagiarized my answer is a matter of opinion because they are slightly different.  My opinion was that your answer was too similar to mine so I downvoted it.  Also, whenever I downvote I say why, because I consider it discourteous and cowardly to downvote without explaining.